# How to add multiple taxonomy term to a single node in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Using Taxonomy terms auto-complete wizard I can able to add one term to the a node. But I wanted to add multiple terms to a single node? Is it possible? If so, is there any modules or plugins or any configuration options in existing module?

[image: my example]

In the above screen shot, I can able to add only one term. But I want to do in the way shown below.

[image: example]

Comment: The *Autocomplete term widget (tagging)* widget that ships with Drupal core should allow for multiple terms separated by a comma. Is that the one you're trying to use?

Comment: So that was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Term Reference *Field settings* of the content type and change '*Number of values*' to  your required value.

For example if you want to allow 2 terms per node change the allowed number of values to '2' from select list. If you want to allow more than 10 or so change the option to 'Unlimited' so that you can insert multiple taxonomy terms to a node separated by '*comma*' (,).

Here I've provided screenshot to allow unlimited values. Here 'SECONDTERM' is my    Term Reference of Autocomplete term widget field label name.

[image]